# Jquery dependent multiple select option not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to use jQuery Dependent Selects, if i select multiple value from options available it will fetch the result of my selection.
it works fine with normal select; but if i change the select to multiple it won't give any result it gives empty result when I alert the result.

reference is her [jQuery Dependent Selects](https://github.com/markjs/jquery-dependent-selects)

my code is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
echo'
<form method=post action="">
<select name="location[]" class="dependent-demo4" id="mydropdown" multiple>
<option></option>';
while($ro=$db->fetch_array($result)){
        $bulding=$ro['bulding'];
        $block=$ro['block'];
        <option value='$block'> $bulding > $block </option>";
}
echo'</select><input type=submit name=submit value=submit> </form>';




<script>
$("#mydropdown").on('change', function(evt, params) {
alert($(this).val());
//alert(params.selected);
});
$(function(){
$('.dependent-demo4').dependentSelects({
  labels: ['District: ', 'Region: '],
  placeholderOption: ['Select a district', 'Select a region'],
  placeholderSelect: ['Please select a city', 'Please select a district']
});        
})
</script>
```

Comment: I have a second question, if selected only $bulding it suppose to give all available result tied with that $bulding; but it wont give any ??

please any advice is very welcome